# Sleepsort in Go

Tags: go, concurrency

I implemented sleepsort in Go. I am new to channels, and I'd like to get some advice on them, especially on how to close channels after N messages have been sent on them. Currently I use a counter and an if statement (see the second for loop in `Sleepsort`), but maybe this can be done in a nicer way?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func sleep(n int, channel chan<- int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)
    channel <- n
}

func Sleepsort(xs []int) []int {
    channel := make(chan int, len(xs))
    for _, x := range xs {
        go sleep(x, channel)
    }

    result := make([]int, len(xs))
    i := 0
    for x := range channel {
        result[i] = x
        i++
        if i == len(xs) {
            close(channel)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    xs := []int{2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5}
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", Sleepsort(xs))
}
```

Other advice is also very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm self-answering since I found a nicer way to do this.

In this case, you can loop from 0 to N and receive from the channel manually, rather than using `range`.

```
for i := 0; i < len(xs); i++ {
    result[i] = <-channel
}
close(channel)
```

`close(channel)` is not strictly needed here since the channel would already be closed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Or even, `for i := range result { result[i] = <-channel }`: http://play.golang.org/p/KeSVFxJcYF